# In openssl TLS1.3, will SSL_write yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ ? And will SSL_read yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

There is no re-negotiation in TLS1.3, will SSL_write yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ?  And will SSL_read yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE?

Here are openssl docs in SSL_write and SSL_read
[image]
[image]

Comment: These 2 codes are not related specifically to renegotiation. THey can happen because of the renegotiation, but also because of other reasons. As such there is no reasons to not expect them in TLS 1.3 or any other TLS version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an issue in github, and got the developer's answer.

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11211#event-3094172350

In TLS1.3, SSL_write can yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ, and SSL_read also can yield SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE